# Bucketizing record counts by the hour of this day only and showing hours in axis even without record

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm starting with Google Data Studio. So I have this `event_date` (YYYYMMDD) and `event_timestamp` (Unix epoch in microseconds) columns for each record from BigQuery (original datasource is Firebase). I created a time-series / bar chart (I tried both) that displays the x-axis as hour of the current day (I filtered on `event_date`) and the y-axis as the number of records.

The way I did this is to create a calculated field using the Data Studio function `HOUR(event_timestamp)` and then displayed as `HH`. The problem here is for certain hours that we don't have any corresponding record, there is no entry for the x-axis. What I want is even if there are no records for that specific hour, it will still show. So basically, the x-axis numbers looks like this:

```
00, 01, 02, ..., 22, 23
```

Side question: I noticed that the time series chart sorts from most recent to oldest. How can I reverse the sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple ways to do so that basically rely on an `OUTER JOIN` with all possible dimension values (0-23h).

To frame the problem I will use a BigQuery public dataset: `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire` where `start_date` is a `TIMESTAMP` field containing the time when each ride started. I will filter out all trips that started before 7 AM with the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`
WHERE
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM start_date) > 6
```

Therefore I get the same problem when creating a data source with the previous custom query (hours without data are not displayed):

[image]

---

### Blending with range data

The first and quick fix would be to create a data source that contains all possible dimension values. This could be done in a spreadsheet or, for example, with an additional 0 B custom query:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 23)) AS hour
```

and now we blend the data so that the hour array is on the left side (Data Studio uses `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) and join with `HOUR(start_date)` from the `cycle_hire` table:

[image]

Then we get the desired histogram (be sure to change the number of bars up to 24 in the `STYLE` tab and sort by `hour` ascending in the `DATA` one):

[image]

---

### Aggregate in BigQuery

Another alternative would be to run the calculations for the hourly buckets already in the custom query. For example, in this case, we would generate the hour array, left outer join it with the aggregated data and substitute `NULL` for 0:

```sql
WITH
hours AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 23)) AS hour),
bike_rides AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM start_date) AS hour,
    COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`
  WHERE
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM start_date) > 6
  GROUP BY
    hour )

SELECT
  hour,
  IF(total IS NULL,0,total) AS total
FROM
  bike_rides
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  hours
USING
  (hour)
```

which gives the same result.